# Create an apps for a facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I must create an apps on an old facebook page for a contest.. I looked all facebook page for help, for developers, and nothing..

I have a page for example with exactly wath i need (if you want : https://www.facebook.com/coppertone).

- (1) First they have a link on the page named "Enter Contest" to access on the app.
- (2) Second they have a started page with a like button who block users who haven't  "like" the page.

Screenshop : http://www.kreatoo.com/rav/facebook_like.png

I have a page, and an app, but i realy don't understand how I can link both.. ?

Thank you all for help :)

PS : I'm realy sorry for my bad english

Comment: You sound a little out of your depth here... this is going to require coding expertise. You can't just grab Coppertone's HTML and have everything work.

Comment: Sure, i don't want create that without coding, but can't find how i can do that..

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/

Comment: I have already read all the facebook doc, and all the help part (with forum and questions) and nothing...

Comment: Nothing? Their docs tell you exactly how to make that sort of Facebook Tab. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/ have everything you need.

Comment: I haved read this page too, but i have added informations on "Website with Facebook Login" and i can't add Tab if app have they informations (and can't delete too). So i have create an other app abs it's work.. Now i must block this page if they don't like it

Answer (score 0):

Go here:

http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/Courses/TableOfContents?courseName=intro-fb-dev

It's a high level intro on developing for facebook, after watching this you should be able to read the docs and dive a little deeper. But I second ceejayoz, you are not going to be able to just throw together an functioning app without getting into the code quite a bit. If its out of your skillset, maybe try to high a freelancer to do it for you.

EDIT: pluralsight is a paid subscription site, but I believe they offer a free trial. if you have the spare change and want to learn more about coding I will highly recommend them